# Trouble drawing Sierpinski with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to generate the Sierpinski Gasket using a function that draws dot patterns and will generate the gasket.

But when I compile and run the program it displays nothing but black screen.  What's causing the problem?

Here is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <glut.h>

void myInit(void) {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 640.0, 0.0, 480.0);
}

class GLintPoint {
    public:
        GLint x, y;
    };

    int random(int m) {
        return rand() % m;
    }

    void drawDot(GLint x, GLint y)
    {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i(x, y);
        glEnd();
    }

    void Sierpinski(void) {
    GLintPoint T[3] = {{ 10, 10 }, {300, 30}, {200, 300}};

    int index = random(3);
    GLintPoint point = T[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        index = random(3);
        point.x = (point.x + T[index].x) / 2;
        point.y = (point.y + T[index].y) / 2;
        drawDot(point.x, point.y);
    }
    glFlush();
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski Gasket");
    glutDisplayFunc(drawDot);
    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to draw something simple, like a white dot and a black dot?

Comment: Yes, they draw perfectly, but this won't draw anything.

Comment: Please also show minimal code which successfully draws something, for reference. The problem is likely to be found in the difference of working similar code and non-working code.

Comment: FYI If you are starting to lean OpenGL I suggest you start with modern (Core Profile) rather than the legacy API. Function calls like `glBegin`, `glEnd`, etc were made legacy in 2008: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL and will be (or have been) deprecated.

Comment: Here is a piece of code that successfully draws 3 points:
    void myDisplay(void) 
    {
    glClearColor(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(100, 50);
    glVertex2i(100, 130);
    glVertex2i(150, 130);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw black dots on a white background, then you have to clear [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) the background:

```
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
```

Note, [`glClearColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml) sets the color which is used to clear the view port, but doesn't clear anything itself.

Your code should look somehow like this:

```
void drawDot(GLint x, GLint y)
{
    glVertex2i(x, y);
}

void Sierpinski(void) {
    GLintPoint T[3] = {{ 10, 10 }, {300, 30}, {200, 300}};

    int index = random(3);
    GLintPoint point = T[index];

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // set up white clear color
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );   // clear the back ground (white)

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPushMatrix();                   // setup model matrix
    glScalef( 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.0f );     // scale the point distribution

    glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );    // set black draw color
    glPointSize( 5.0f );              // set the size of the points 
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        index = random(3);
        point.x = (point.x + T[index].x) / 2;
        point.y = (point.y + T[index].y) / 2;
        drawDot(point.x, point.y);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();                    // reset model matrix

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: This solved it, I forgot to set the color of the drawing function. Thanks.

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehtab  See the changes to the answer. You have to call `glClear`

Comment: Ok, got it.
But the output is very small, how to make it a little bigger?

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehtab Use [`glPointSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPointSize.xhtml)

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehtab The distribution of the points can be scaled by [`glScalef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml). See the changes to the answer.